# How to create an advanced search form using the Drupal 8 Solr Search module?

Tags: php, search, drupal, solr, drupal-8

We are using the Drupal 8 Solr Search module, but originally this module only contains a simple search form. We would like to have an advanced search form, but we don't know how and where to begin to implement a custom one. Some sources recommended using Solr Facets but this is not enough for us.

Comment: what did you try? what do you mean it's not enough?

Comment: We would like search in specific criteria for exampke in title index or any other custom created index. At the moment the Drupal 8 Solr Search only has a simple one input field search box which is search in every Solr index.
At the moment we don't have any idea how to achieve our goal.

Comment: Solr Facet is not enough because it is only good when you want to use fix criterias with fix options. We would like offer the user to type any word.

Comment: It can be like the Google Advanced Search: https://www.google.com/advanced_search, but a little simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way without programming anything. In the Solr Search config page (Structure / Views) you can use the Views exposed filter to add as many index specific form input as you want.